# google app engines blobstore and geographical replication

Tags: google-app-engine, replication, blobstore, geo

I am wondering about safety and availability (single data center outage) of data stored inside app engines blobstore. For example, HR datastore uses paxos to distribute data among different datacenters ( https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/overview ), and Google Cloud Storage geographically distributes data too ( https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/faq ). So how about blobstore? Are all my data stored in single datacenter or there are some HA features built in afterall?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blobs stored in  blobstore are replicated to multiple data centres.